# Validate Column should allow only Integer/positive/Negative values

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a column Quantity NUMBER(12). I need to check this column should not allow any decimal and 0 values for it were as Negative and positive values are allowed.

For this I have written a query

```
select case when trim(TRANSLATE('quantity','+-123456789', ' ')) is null
            then 'T'
            else 'F'
       end
from dual
```

The above query is not working fine when the `quantity like 10/100/1000 etc`.

Please help me to modify the query to allow 10 or 100 or etc but only not allow +-0.

Comment: Why not use an int rather than a number field.  Then you only need to check it is > 0

Comment: @Teepu - Removed MySQL tag as it looks like Oracle query and `translate` doesn't work on MySQL.

Comment: It should allow even negative values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: Change the case statement to handle `0`.
Note: `-0`,`0`,`+0` are same and stored in DB as `0` only.

```
case when trim(TRANSLATE(quantity,'-1234567890', ' ')) is null 
and quantity<>0
```

Sample example

```
with tbl (quantity) as
(select 1.1 from dual union all
select 10 from dual union all
select 100 from dual union all
select 1000 from dual union all
select -44 from dual union all
select  0 from dual union all
select -0 from dual union all
select +0 from dual)
select quantity,case when trim(TRANSLATE(quantity,'-1234567890', ' ')) is null 
and quantity<>0
            then 'T'
            else 'F'
       end as is_int
from tbl
```

Output

```
+----------+--------+
| Quantity | IS_INT |
+----------+--------+
|      1.1 | F      |
|       10 | T      |
|      100 | T      |
|     1000 | T      |
|      -44 | T      |
|        0 | F      |
|        0 | F      |
|        0 | F      |
+----------+--------+
```

Comment: But the query should not accept 0 or -0 or +0 how can I do that?

Comment: Check the updated answer. If it works for you then accept it to question could be closed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the MYSQL database then you can simply alter the table and make it as `signed int`. Like this:

```
ALTER TABLE 'myTable' MODIFY 'quantity' INT SIGNED
```

In PLSQL:

```
alter table
   myTable
modify
   quantity INT;

alter table myTable
    modify quantity INT,
         constraint ckValue check (quantity <> 0);
```

Comment: @Strawberry:- Didnt see the zero part. Updated my answer. Thanks for pointing.

Comment: I cannot go for check constraint because i need to mark the records as ERROR  so that user can correct it .